# what is wrong with this php code shown as below?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

In the code below , the else part is working fine , but if the email is not there in database , why the javascript   alert   --- ('This email id doesnt exist in our records')  not working ? . If the else part is working why the num_rows=0 not working . I tried a lot . A help will be appreciated.

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$em = $_POST['email'];

$qry = mysql_query("select * from user where  email_id='$em' ")or die(mysql_error());
$num = mysql_num_rows($qry);
if(is_null($num))
{
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('This email id doesn't exist  in our records');
    </script> 
    <?php
}
else
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
    {
        $email_id = $row['email_id'];
        $name = $row['user_login_id'];
        $password= $row['password'];
    }

    if($email_id)
    {
        $to= $email_id;
        $subject=" Password Recovery Mail";
        $message="Let US REMIND YOU!!  Your  username - ".$name. " and     Password - ".$password;
        $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $header.="From:<donotreply@jassasia.com>"."\r\n"; 
        $n=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
        ?> <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Check your Mail, <?php echo $email_id; ?>, for your username and  password');
        window.location="index.php";
        </script> 
        <?php
    }
}
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8"><br/>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid #ddd;"><br/>
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
                    <h2>Hope you remember your registered email id...</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Enter the registered email id</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"  id="" placeholder="Enter the email id " required autofocus>
                            <input type="submit" id="sub" name="forgotpass" value="Continue">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) checks if the variable is `NULL`, not that it's zero.

Comment: If you can, you should stop using mysql_* functions. They are officially deprecated. These extensions have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about prepared statements instead, and consider using PDO, it's really not hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would fist check the console messages since I think your alert function is not working at all even though it comes on it cause of the ' that you used in text.

Change this

```
  alert('This email id doesn't exist  in our records');
```

to

```
  alert("This email id doesn't exist  in our records"); // See the "
```

Cheers

Comment: Oh wot a silly mistake . Thanks a lot it worked .. but the else part alert is in ' ' ,but it worked instead of " " .. y so ?

Comment: In the else part alert you dont have the ' in the text. 

If you start putting the parameter with ' then the second ' will be the end point of it. In the first alert you are closing the parameter scope with using the ' in the text and the rest is just gybrish for JS, it thinks you have a mistake which is true.

Comment: oh the ' of doesn't caused the mess of it .!! Anyways Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

change this

```
if(is_null($num))
```

to this

```
if(empty($num))
```

**And**

change this

```
if($email_id)
```

to this

```
if(isset($email_id))
```

Comment: `empty($num)` will check for `0` also. No need for `|| $num ==0`.

Comment: @Moderator - the alert message is not poping .

Comment: @Sayuj3 so it mean ther is a data with that associate data(email)

Comment: no it got solved jus t becoz of ' ' instead of " " inside alert

Answer (score 0):

Compare your variable $num against 0 and FALSE. Since mysql_num_rows function returns in integer on success and return FALSE on failure.

```
if( $num ==0 && $num!=FALSE)
```

AND Check $email agains empty or isset

```
if(isset($email) && $email!="")
```

Answer (score 0):

`$num = mysql_num_rows($qry);` gives you the number of count of no of rows retrieved else `FALSE`, indicating 0 records.

So when you do a check `if(is_null($num))` it will never enter the if clause, because the `mysql_num_rows($qry);` will never return `NULL`.

you need to change that to

```
<? if($num == FALSE)
    {
?>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       alert('This email id doesn't exist  in our records');
     </script>
```

Comment: can u check whats the value of `$num` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all to introduce Javascript alert box inside PHP code you need to call a function. Try the below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_alertMsg() {
        var msg = "This email id doesn't exist  in our records.";
        alert(msg);
    }
</script>
 if(is_null($num))
   {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript"> show_alertMsg(); </script>';
   }
else {
   // your code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        <?php
     include 'db.php';
       $em = $_POST['email'];

    $qry = mysql_query("select * from user where  email_id='$em' ")or    die(mysql_error());

    if( mysql_num_rows($qry)  < 0)
    {
      ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         alert('This email id doesn't exist  in our records');
</script> 
<?php
}
 else
 {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    $email_id = $row['email_id'];
    $name = $row['user_login_id'];
    $password= $row['password'];
}

if($email_id)
{
    $to= $email_id;
    $subject=" Password Recovery Mail";
    $message="Let US REMIND YOU!!  Your  username - ".$name. " and     Password - ".$password;
    $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $header.="From:<donotreply@jassasia.com>"."\r\n"; 
    $n=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
    ?> <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Check your Mail, <?php echo $email_id; ?>, for your username and  password');
    window.location="index.php";
    </script> 
    <?php
}
}
?>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"><br/>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid #ddd;"><br/>
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST">
                <h2>Hope you remember your registered email id...</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Enter the registered email id</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"  id="" placeholder="Enter the email id " required autofocus>
                        <input type="submit" id="sub" name="forgotpass" value="Continue">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will contain an explanation of what was done, which will be valuable for the OP and future visitors to SO.